# Poisson process vs selecting based on a probability

Tags: poisson-process

I want to write a function that returns an error with a rate of `n%` . I am confused if the following two ways are the same or what is the difference.

- poisson process with λ=n/100
- each time function is called, return failure if a 100 sided dice rolls a number less than or equal to `n`

Comment: One is a Poisson process and the other is a Bernoulli process.  Why do you think a Poisson process might be appropriate?

Comment: > Why do you think a Poisson process might be appropriate?  
    

@jbowman , The function simulates a service that can fail. If we know the avg number of failures but each failure is independent of other failures, I think that is a poisson process?